# strtotime - check if 24 hours are elasped in php give wrong result

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I need to compare two dates to check if 24 hours are elasped.
I've writed this php if statement that is supposed to do the comparision

```php
if( strtotime($this->get_current_date('d-m-Y')) > strtotime($customer_details['approved_date']) ){
//do something...
}
```

The get_current_time function looks like this

```php
function get_current_date( string $format )
{
  $date = new DateTime();
  $formattedDate = $date->format($format);
  return $formattedDate;
}
```

As i know the `strtotime` php function will convert a valid string that will hold time numeric value into a date. What is happening is that the comparision will not give the expected result. If the date is the same for example both dates are `12-10-2023` it will evaluate the expression for true also if 24 hours are not passed. How I can correctly do the check and fix this?

**UPDATE**

I've currently updated my code to store into the database a timestamp created using the `time()` function of php. I've also modified the code for the check in this way and during a new test I've noticed that the system will continue to send the email also if 24 hours aren't elasped. Now I will have a check in this way to get the current timestamp

```php
   $today = new DateTime();
   $formatted_today_date = $today->format('d-m-Y');
```

and this code to do the check. Probably I will need to do it in another way?

```php
 $time = $customer_details['approved_date'];
 $registration_date = new DateTime("@$time");
 $formatted_registration_date = $registration_date->format('d-m-Y');
                    
 if( strtotime($formatted_today_date) > strtotime($formatted_registration_date) && empty($customer_details['last_password_reset']) && !(bool)$customer_details['account_details_sent'] || empty($customer_details['account_details_sent']) ){
    ...
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If both dates are equal, then `>` should not pass: https://3v4l.org/qIC27

Comment: @ChrisHaas I don't know why the check will fail and the mail are sent also if 24 hours are not elasped. I've done a test on php playground and as you've linked the test will fail. During debug I've tried to set a date greater than today and the script sended the mail, but this is wrong

Comment: What format is the `$customer_details['approved_date']` in?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it will return a string in this format `02-11-2023` in other part of the codes this will work correctly I also have a custom function for the check where I'm checking if a password is expired after 60 days, only for this verification I've problems